# How to find a tag within the same parent that has the child I want?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Scraping a website that has multiple products on the same page, some that I don't want to know the prices of. So I wanted to first see the product category to then get the price listed.

The website code looks like this:

```
<section class="products_results">
   <span something I don't want>...</span>
   <section class="category">
      <span>Clothes</span>
   <div something I don't want>...</div>
   <section class="search_result_price">
      <section>
         <span something I don't want>...</span>
         <span class="price">149.99</span>
      </section>
</section>
```

I already know how to get to the category part with my own code, but I'm completely stuck on the other part.

```
for products in soup.find_all(class_='category'):
   category = (products.text)
   if category == 'Clothes':
      price = (theoretical piece of code)
```

How can I get to the specific price tag within this parent `<section>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close to your goal but be aware that `products.text` will give you the whole section text, better use `products.span.text` to get the category text only.

To get the price info, simply find the span with `class="price"` and check if it is available or not to avoid errors:

```
price = products.find(class_='price').text if products.find('span', class_='price') else None
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<section class="products_results">
   <span something I don't want>...</span>
   <section class="category">
      <span>Clothes</span>
   <div something I don't want>...</div>
   <section class="search_result_price">
      <section>
         <span something I don't want>...</span>
         <span class="price">149.99</span>
      </section>
</section>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for products in soup.find_all('section', class_='category'):
    category = products.span.text
    if category == 'Clothes':
        price = products.find(class_='price').text if products.find('span', class_='price') else None
        print(price)
```

###### Output

```
149.99
```

---

As alternative an approach that is more lean, creates a structured output that is easy to process and deals with a list of permitted categories:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    html='''
    <section class="products_results">
       <span something I don't want>...</span>
       <section class="category">
          <span>Clothes</span>
       <div something I don't want>...</div>
       <section class="search_result_price">
          <section>
             <span something I don't want>...</span>
             <span class="price">149.99</span>
          </section>
       <span something I don't want>...</span>
       <section class="category">
          <span>Shoes</span>
       <div something I don't want>...</div>
       <section class="search_result_price">
          <section>
             <span something I don't want>...</span>
             <span class="price">90.99</span>
          </section>
    </section>'''
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    
    data = []
    
    c_list = ['Clothes','Shoes']
    
    for products in soup.select(f"section.category:-soup-contains({','.join(c_list)})"):
        data.append({
            'category' : products.span.text,
            'price' : products.find(class_='price').text if products.find('span', class_='price') else None
        })
    
    data
```

###### Output

```
[{'category': 'Clothes', 'price': '149.99'},
 {'category': 'Shoes', 'price': '90.99'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use from regex

```py
Import re
Pat = '''
price">(/d*./d*)</span>
'''
price = re.find_all(your text,pat)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this at all, can you elaborate a little?
What is the Pat here?

Comment: regex is a very very strong library for distinguish text patterns and have very good methods that can help you in text extracting. Pat is text pattern that i define with regex standard that can find it in text. Study about it from w3school.com

Comment: Ok, so from what I can see I'd need to get the entire section into a text pattern, and then  on the re.find_all() I'd do re.find_all(/d*./*d, pat), right? If so, what can I do to copy the text from each product in a loop?